# Stuck inside nextGaussian() method

Tags: java, random, normal-distribution

I have a break point directly after a call to nextGaussian() method in eclipse. The code takes forever to run, and when I pause it it shows that it's in the StrictMath.log(double) inside of RandomPlus(Random).nextGaussian() which is inside of RandomPLus.normalRand(double mean, double std).

Below is my random plus code:

```
public class RandomPlus extends Random{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public double NormalRand(double mean, double standardDeviation) {
        return mean + (this.nextGaussian() * standardDeviation);
    }

    public boolean draw(double probability) {
        return this.nextDouble() < probability;
    }
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that I call this method ~ 100.000 times with every time creating a new instance of it.

Comment: What exactly did you run that takes long?

Comment: i was initalizing weights of neuralnetworks. some how splitting this.nextGaussian() on to its own line fixed this problem >.>. i still don't understand why would it be stuck inside of this method and never returned though >.>